# MySQL query not returning all records from a date range when called from a cron job

Tags: php, mysql, date, cron

Here is my problem.

I have a MySQL table containing details from an order form which is processed from a php script. The details captured are products ordered, store location etc...  I can see that all of the required details are being saved to the database without any problems.

Now i have a script which is being called from a cron job twice a day. This script queries the database for orders within a certain date range and then saves the output to a text file which the user then downloads and processes with their third party software.

My problem is that this script being called by the cron job is missing some orders but this does not happen all of the time.

If i run the exact same query which is called by the cron job manually in phpmyadmin the orders appear in the output.

Is there anything that i should be looking at to make sure that all of the orders are captured.

Thanks in advance for any help.

---

**Query 1 - this cron runs at 12:05pm everyday**

```
SELECT o.orderID, o.orderTotal, oi.code, oi.orderQty, p.prodName, p.prodCode, s.store_name, s.store_address
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN items oi ON o.orderID = oi.orderID
INNER JOIN products p ON oi.productID = p.prod_id
INNER JOIN store s ON o.orderStoreID = s.store_id 
WHERE o.orderDateTime BETWEEN CAST('$overnightStart' AS DATETIME) AND CAST('$overnightEnd' AS DATETIME)
```

---

**Query 2: cron runs at 9:05pm everyday**

```
SELECT o.orderID, o.orderTotal, oi.code, oi.orderQty, p.prodName, p.prodCode, s.store_name, s.store_address
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN items oi ON o.orderID = oi.orderID
INNER JOIN products p ON oi.productID = p.prod_id
INNER JOIN store s ON o.orderStoreID = s.store_id 
WHERE o.orderDateTime BETWEEN CAST('$todayStart' AS DATETIME) AND CAST('$todayEnd' AS DATETIME)
```

---

Here is the code which I use to generate the dates.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Victoria');
$overnightStart = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("yesterday 21:00:00"));
$overnightEnd   = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("today 11:59:59"));
$todayStart     = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("today 12:00:00"));
$todayEnd       = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("today 20:59:59"));
```

Comment: The Dates you are using in Query... are they static in your code or your are getting from PHP code?

Comment: As an aside, note that MySQL's datetime resolution [is finer than a single second](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html), so these queries may be missing out orders anyway (e.g. it looks like an order placed at 2014-10-27 11:59:59.5 might not be picked up by your first query, when you're probably expecting it to pick up all orders up to midnight.) But yes, as @Croises observes, your problem is likely that the dates that you're using aren't the ones you think you're using, due to server/connection timezone settings.

Comment: @Umair the dates are calculated via PHP on the date the script is ran which is everyday twice a day.

Comment: Please run that Cron Script from browser and  `echo` your queries in browser and than run into PHPmyAdmin ... By this way you will have more debug info ... and then let me know ...

Comment: @Umair i have echoed the cron query and ran it in phpmyadmin and all of the orders now appear for the date range. This has me stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have a problem with PHP timezone.
If the cron job don't use the same time zone, some orders can be wrote after cron job, but for dates before.
And after when you try more than 1 hour after (or more, the delta time zone), it's ok

Comment: i am using easycron.com to run the cron job. The timezone for the cron is set to my local timezone which is also the same timezone as the orderDateTime in the database.

Comment: it might be easier if you indicate the php code used to generate the dates.

Comment: i have added the code which i use to generate the dates for the WHERE statement and updated the queries to show where they are used.

Comment: I think you have also checked that this is the same in all your orders pages (date_default_timezone_set).